# Set Audio to the Speakers with Headphones plugged in

Tags: sound, headphones, speakers

For some weeks I was unable to use Ubuntu due to Windows 8 preventing its boot, so I noticed an interesting function that I missed in Ubuntu:

In Windows 8 when I plug-in my headphones I was able to open the mixer options and set the speakers to reproduce the audio, even with the headphones plugged and more than that I was able to handle my skype conversations through the headphone while listening to my music, or youtube videos, or games in the speakers.

Although in Ubuntu when I go "Sound Settings..." > "Output" I was unable to redirect the audio to the speakers while the headphone was connected. I have three options: Digital Output (S/PDIF) *Built-In Audio*; Analog Output *Built-In Audio*; and Analog Headphone Output *Built-In Audio*. When I choose Digital I have no audio at all, in any situation. Although it doesn't matter if I choose Analog or Analog Headphone the audio will be headed to the headphone.

Then I noticed that it was a problem: I am not able to use the speakers while my headphones are connected, the main point here is not to separate audio from skype, from the other things, I guess (and hope) that it can be easily set in skype settings once the main problem is fixed: set the speakers as primary reproduction devices even when my headphones are plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

edit /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-headphones.conf

And in section [element speakers], try to change switch=on into switch=off

Comment: It didn't work, switch is already off, although I tried setting to on, then restarting the PC and nothing changes, also tried changin' [Element Headphones], [Element Headphones 2] [Element Desktop Speakers] and nothing changed...

Comment: same, i have tried so many times, anyone know how to fix this?